# How access all forms inside a <frameset><iframe>?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want access all elements inside of `<form>` of a webpage that load these forms inside a `<frameset><iframe>`,

[image]

then i have created this code below but not works.

Already when is a page that not starts with a `iframe` works fine.

How solve this?

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Chrome webrequest test",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "A test for webrequest",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "permissions": [
    "tabs", "background", "activeTab", "<all_urls>", "webNavigation", "webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "*://*/*"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": "img/flash128.png",
        "default_title": "Chrome webrequest"
  },
    "icons" : {
      "48" : "img/flash48.png"  
    }
}
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.webRequest.onCompleted.addListener(
     function OnWebRequestCompleted() {
      chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
       file: "Inject.js"
      }, function() {});
     }, {
      urls: ["<all_urls>"],
      types: ["main_frame"]
     }, ["responseHeaders"]);
```

**Inject.js**

```
var url = document.URL;

if (url.indexOf("site.com") != -1) {

 var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form");
 var btnclass = document.getElementsByClassName("btnClassName");
 var inputField = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

 for (var x = 0; x < form.length; x++) {

  //  document.body.addEventListener('DOMSubtreeModified', function() {

  for (var i = 0; i < btnclass.length; i++) {

   btnclass[i].addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    for (var i = 0; i < inputField.length; i++) {

     alert(inputField[i].value);

    }

   }, false);
  }

  // }, false);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your iframe is a different document.  Where you currently use `document.getElementsBy*` you will need to change to something like

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('frameID');
var innerDoc = iframe.contentDocument
innerDoc.getElementsBy*...
```